# Array list not being passed into OnItemClickListener()

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am trying to pass data into an intent, I have added a onclicklistener method on onCreate(), but for some reason  when I press any list view item it is not opening the intent for me. the array list is not on the same class as the main activity.
here is my **MainActivity (onCreate)** code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    new GetRestaurants(places,this,lv).execute();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    ArrayAdapter<Restaurant> adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, 0, places);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.customListView);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    AdapterView.OnItemClickListener adapterViewListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            Restaurant restaurant = places.get(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailActivity.class);

            intent.putExtra("name", restaurant.getName());


            startActivity(intent);

        }
    };
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(adapterViewListener);


    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


}
```

**my intent activity:**

```
public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.detail_layout);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    TextView nameTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);


    Intent intent = getIntent();

    String name1= intent.getStringExtra("name");

    nameTV.setText(name1);

}}
```

And here is my **custom adapter** which gets the restaurant details:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Restaurant> {
private Context context;
private List<Restaurant> places;

public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Restaurant> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    this.context = context;
    this.places = objects;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {



    Restaurant restaurant = places.get(position);

    //get the inflater and inflate the XML layout for each item
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_layout, null);

    TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
    TextView address1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.address1);
    TextView menu = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.menu);
    TextView price = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.price);
    TextView phone = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.phone);
    TextView rate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.rate);
    name.setText("Name " + restaurant.getName());
    address1.setText("Address " +restaurant.getAddress1());
    menu.setText("Cuisine "+restaurant.getMenu_type());
    price.setText("Price " + Integer.toString(restaurant.getCost()));
    phone.setText("Phone " +Integer.toString(restaurant.getPhone()));
    rate.setText( "Rate " +Float.toString(restaurant.getRate()));


    return view;
}}
```

and here is the error I am getting once I click on any item on the list view after it get populated:

```
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
com.example.abdulhakim.navbar.MainActivity$1.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:52)
03-05 22:02:53.212 25306-25306/com.example.abdulhakim.navbar
```

Code for

**GetRestaurant**

```
public class GetRestaurants extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private String host ="";
    private String port = "";
    private String Search="/api/restaurants/search/";
    private String getplace="/api/restaurants/search/";
    private String register="api/users/add";
    private String url = "http://#DELETED#/api/restaurants/search/?key=Burger&col=menu_type";
    private String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private ArrayList<Restaurant>places;
    private Context context;
    private Dialog dialog;
    private ListView lv;


    public  GetRestaurants(ArrayList<Restaurant> places,Context context,ListView lv) {
        this.places = places;
        this.context=context;
        this.lv=lv;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(context,ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        ArrayAdapter<Restaurant> adapter = new CustomAdapter(context, 0, places);
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.customListView);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (dialog.isShowing())
            dialog.dismiss();
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        places = new ArrayList<>();

        HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

        Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);
        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                // Getting JSON Array node
                JSONArray restaurants = jsonObj.getJSONArray("restaurants");

                // looping through the JSON object
                for (int i = 0; i < restaurants.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = restaurants.getJSONObject(i);

                    String  id = c.getString("id");
                    String name = c.getString("name");
                    String address1 = c.getString("address1");
                    String address2 = c.getString("address2");
                    String lat = c.getString("lat");
                    String lng = c.getString("lng");
                    String cost = c.getString("cost");
                    String menu_type = c.getString("menu_type");
                    String rate = c.getString("rate");
                    String offer = c.getString("offer");
                    // Phone node is JSON Object
                    String mobile = c.getString("phone");

                    places.add(new Restaurant(Integer.parseInt(id),name,address1,address2,Integer.parseInt(mobile)
                            ,Float.parseFloat(lat),Float.parseFloat(lng)
                            ,Integer.parseInt(cost),menu_type,Float.parseFloat(rate),offer));
                }
            }
            catch (final JSONException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your places list in the onItemClick is empty, probably you actually want to reference the one from the adapter at that point

Comment: How would I do that? I thought the line 
             "   Restaurant restaurant = places.get(position);"
 does it?

Comment: Well it depends how you have set the whole classes up, i can't tell since the places declaration which you are referencing isn't in the code provided. For a better understanding at how you should set it up, look at scopes of variables in general

Comment: ArrayAdapter<Restaurant> adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, 0, places); here i do not see where you declare places.

Comment: this line , does it populate it correctly: new GetRestaurants(places,this,lv).execute();

Comment: Yes it does.
 I am getting a list full of places, but once I touch any of the items  on the list nothing happens except the outbound exception.

Comment: Please add code for your `GetRestaurants` class

Comment: @AngeloParente I have added the code, GetRestaurants is a inner class of MainAcitivity.

Comment: **1-** error means you try to access an element in arraylist which is out of range (items count =0, you are clicking  on 1st item) in short words,  list is empty, `places` but how can you click on ListView when list is empty?! **2-** in `onPostexecute()` you don't have to redeclare/assign everything, first, declare your adapter as class global scope, and then you call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`